# How can I use webpack without the .jsx extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have set the webpack config file and added the extension parameter under the resolve object. But webpack still requires me to add the extension .jsx . I also added the aliases but still no success please help.

This is part of the configuration

```
module.exports = { 
  entry: './public/app.jsx', 
  output: { 
    path:__dirname, 
    filename: './public/bundle.js' 
  }, 
  resolve: { 
    root: __dirname, 
    alias: { 
      Greeter : 'public/components/Greeter.jsx', 
      GreeterMessage : 'public/components/GreeterMessage.jsx', 
      GreeterForm : 'public/components/GreeterForm.jsx', 
    }, 
    extension: ['','.js','.jsx'] 
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share your webpack config?

Comment: Please post the configuration here.

Comment: `module.exports =  {
  entry: './public/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path:__dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Greeter : 'public/components/Greeter.jsx',
      GreeterMessage : 'public/components/GreeterMessage.jsx',
      GreeterForm : 'public/components/GreeterForm.jsx',
    },
    extension: ['','.js','.jsx']
  }`@NanduKalidindi && @djfdev

i don't have up to 10 points to upload image. that's part of the config file. If the image is still required i can upload to an image hosting service and share with you.

Comment: Maybe your loader tests for `/\.jsx$/` which could be a reason

Comment: @EugenBleckBleck Please edit your post in case you wish to add something, do not add it in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the loader you're using, likely `babel-loader`, you'd need to add the regex like this to use js or jsx.

`test: /\.js|.jsx$/`

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/